# Files doesn't shown on Desktop

Tags: files

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.1. and I'm newbie on Linux systems. Trying to learn =)

As you see within the added SS [Desktop SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVBob.png), I have 4 files on my /Desktop called "asd, asd1, isim and serhat" but There aren't visible and existing on Desktop. I can just see them in Folder and Terminal, but can not [Desktop SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVBob.png)

What the funk is this problem that I facing? Is there any possible solution?

Comment: Notice your Desktop does not even show in the Files location along the left side.  Please  add ls -ld ~/Desktop output to your question.

Comment: @ubfan1 Before your instructions, I did thedler's and it works. Thank you too.

Answer (score 0):

Install the shell extension

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng
```

and it should work immediately.

Comment: I did it and after reboot It works. Thank you so much. But still I'm curious about what was happen desktop icons and right click features. I think it happens after I did something.

Comment: @Yuri, if an answer has helped you, please upvote it.